# If cell value in worksheet(3) matches cell value in worksheet(2) AND specified cell in worksheet(2) contains given text replace with

Tags: vba, excel

If cell value in worksheet 3 matches cell value in worksheet 2 AND specified cell in worksheet 2 contains given text replace with...

(EDIT - Additional explanation from comment): I want to compare Column D in Sheets("New") to Column A in Sheets("alljobs"). If these match I want to go to column G of Sheets("alljobs") and depending on whether it contains GTB or WDTC, I want to change Column B of Sheets("New") to say Disney WDTC or Disney DCL.

Any idea why it runs but doesn't do anything?

```
Sub changedisney()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lookupvalue As Variant

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("April")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("alljobs")
Set ws3 = wb.Sheets("New")

y = ws3.Cells(ws3.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = y To 2 Step -1
        lookupvalue = ws3.Cells(i, 4)
        For x = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row To Step - 1
            Set rng = ws2.Cells(x, 4)
            If rng = lookupvalue And ws2.Cells(x, 7) Like "wdtc*" Then
                ws3.Cells(x, 2) = "Disney WDTC"
            End If
        Next x
    Next i


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub changedisney()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsAll As Worksheet
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim DCell As Range
    Dim rFound As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsAll = wb.Sheets("alljobs")
    Set wsNew = wb.Sheets("New")

    For Each DCell In wsNew.Range("D2", wsNew.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Cells
        Set rFound = wsAll.Columns("A").Find(DCell.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            Select Case LCase(Left(wsAll.Cells(rFound.Row, "G").Text, 3))
                Case "wdt": wsNew.Cells(DCell.Row, "B").Value = "Disney WDTC"
                Case "gtb": wsNew.Cells(DCell.Row, "B").Value = "Disney DCL"
            End Select
        End If
    Next DCell

End Sub
```

**EDIT**: Updated code based on comment from OP:

> I want to compare Column D in wsNew to Column A in wsALL. If these
>   match I want to go to **column G of wsNew** and depending on whether
>   it contains GTB or WDTC, I want to change Column B of wsNew to said
>   Disney WDTC or DIsney DCL

(In your comment, you state to look at column G of wsNew, but I think you meant to say column G of wsAll, which is what the updated code does.)

Comment: sorry no luck. it runs but it doesnt change anything

Comment: I tested it with mock data, so I know it works. If it's not working for you, then the information we have doesn't match how your data is laid out.  Can you please provide some sample data so that we know what we're working with?

Comment: I could take some screenshots how do i send it your way?

Comment: Upload the images to an image storage site (like flickr or imgur) and then get the links to your images and put them in your original question.

Comment: so basically I am trying to look through tab New column "Jobnumber" in tab AllJobs "Jobnumber". If the Jobnumbers match I want to see if the reference column in alljobs either contains gtb or wdtc in which case I want to change the customer column on New tab

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time to look at it now, I will have to look at it tomorrow.

Comment: No rush I won't be back until the 4th.

Comment: @ichoi alright, based on the provided screenshot, it looks like you want to compare wsNew column B with wsAll column C.  That's the only match I can find between the two worksheets (Customer for both is Disney Orlando.  Job Number, AWB, and Master all do NOT match in the provided screenshots).  if that's the case, please see edited answer.

Comment: Sorry the screenshots aren't very indicative of what I want. I just wanted you to see the format. I want to compare Column D in wsNew to Column A in wsALL. If these match I want to go to column G of wsNew and depending on whether it contains GTB or WDTC, I want to change Column B of wsNew to said Disney WDTC or DIsney DCL.

Comment: @ichoi I have updated the answer based on your comment.